# Why doesn't cmake find_package search usr/lib by default

Tags: linux, cmake

According to cmake's documentation cmake searches for these paths on Unix

```
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/                 (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                       (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/         (U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/         (W/U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/               (W/U)
<prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/ (W/U)
```

But usually lot of libraries are also present in `<prefix>/usr/lib`. Adding `/usr` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` enables cmake's `find_package` to see it.

Is there a reason cmake doesn't check this by default?

Edit: consolidating info from comments

1. Its cross compilation
2. Its using FindCurl.cmake, there is no CURLconfig.cmake

Comment: "But usually lot of libraries are also present in `<prefix>/usr/lib`" - Could you provide an example of such library, which cannot be found by `find_package` with default settings.

Comment: @Tsyvarev its `libcurl`. It does not even look there when i set `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON`, it looks at `<prefix>/lib` `<prefix>/bin` and even `<prefix>/usr/bin` but not in `<prefix>/usr/lib`. I am cross compiling if it makes any difference.

Comment: If I understand the CMake documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package#search-procedure) correctly, the platform' s system paths should be searched. See item 7 under the search procedure explanation.

Comment: Well, actually when talk about things under `/usr/lib`, they have installation prefix `/usr` (not `/`). So list of search paths is correct: if `<prefix>` would be set to `/usr`, then CMake will search config files under `/usr/lib`. Why `/usr` is not added to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` by default is another question.

Comment: BTW, which exact Linux distribution provides `curl-config.cmake` file (which would used by `find_package(curl)`? E.g. Ubuntu doesn't provide that file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev from what I understand its using [FindCurl.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) since it cant find the *config.cmake.

@vre The documentation lists the paths but it doens't mention anything about `/usr/lib` or how/what it considers as system path, I am assuming you mean `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`.

Comment: So the paths you list in your question post has nothing common with your problem. These paths are for locate `xxx-config.cmake` (or `XXXConfig.cmake` one), but searching for curl uses `FindXXX.cmake` script. As for [this script](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/FindCURL.cmake) itself, it firstly tries to find curl via `pkg-config`. So, if you have `libcurl.pc` (e.g. Ubuntu [provides it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcurl.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any), then the library will be found successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` was set to 'Generic', and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` was not not set by [Generic.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Generic.cmake)

When I changed `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to Linux, [Linux.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Linux.cmake) and [UnixPaths.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Platform/UnixPaths.cmake) added `/usr` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`